# converter uma string em vb.net - convert.toDouble

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Estou tentando converter uma *string* em `double` em vb.net:

```
 Dim result as double
 Dim ValueString as string = "-42.1942339"
 result = Convert.ToDouble(ValueString)
 Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte valor `-421942339` O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Podes traduzir a pergunta para Português por favor?

Comment: Estou tentando converter uma string em double em vb.net:

 Dim result as double
 dim ValueString as string = -42.1942339
 
 result = Convert.ToDouble(ValueString)

  Console.WriteLine(result)


Estou recebendo o seguinte valor

-421942339

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é a cultura sendo utilizada para fazer a conversão. Provavelmente, seu sistema operacional está configurado para uma cultura que não considera o ponto (i.e. `.`) como separador decimal.

Para fazer a conversão, neste caso não poderá deixar que o método `Convert.ToDouble` utilize a cultura padrão do sistema operacional.

Para isso é possível passar um parâmetro para o método `Convert.ToDouble` indicando a cultura:

```
Convert.ToDouble(ValueString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

- `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`: é uma cultura que não varia com o tempo. O ponto decimal é sempre `.`.

Comment: Vivendo e aprendendo. Muito Obrigado. Só pra deixar registrado precisa importar também -> Imports System.Globalization. Valeu

Comment: Considere aceitar essa resposta se tiver resolvido o problema.